# Mathematic equation solved recursively in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a task to make a code which will write 100 first numbers of an equation (or a function, I don't know what this is)

`A(n) = (A(n-1))^2 -n*A(n-2) where A(1) = 1 and A(2) = 1`

It has to be solved recursively. I have written this code so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int rekurzija(int n){
    if(n=1){
        return 1;
    }
    if(n=2){
        return 1;
    }
    if(n>2){
        return rekurzija(n-1)*rekurzija(n-1)-n*rekurzija(n-2);
    }
}

int main(){
    for(int n=1;n<101;n=n+1){
        cout << rekurzija(n) << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program returns `1` hundred times instead of 1,1,-2,0,...(instead of actually solving this function). What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but you ***really*** don't want to call the function twice to accomplish squaring.  Call it once, store the outcome in `result`, and then use `result * result`.  Your CPU will thank you for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [simple assignment operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_assignment_operators.htm) `=` instead of [Is equals to relational operator](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-relational-operator/) `==` in your `rekurzija()` function for `if` conditions

```
if(n = 1) //here `n = 1`is an assignment statement
{
    //something...
}
```

**What happens if you use `=` instead of `==`?**

The `if` condition will always evaluate to be `true` if the assigned value in the assignment statement is non-zero number.

**Note**: An assignment to zero evaluates to be `false` i.e, for `if(n = 0)`, the `if` block will not be entered. You don't have any such `if` blocks in your code.

So your first `if` is always evaluated to be `true` because you are assigning a non-zero value i.e, `1` and thus your function always returns `1`. that's the reason why you get 100 `1`'s as your answer.

So, instead try changing all the `if` conditions to something like:

```
if(n == 1)
{
    //something...
}
```

This would check if `n` is equals to `1` or not. If `n` is equal to `1` then the `if` block is entered, else it would not enter the `if` block and the next `if` condition is checked.

---

**Note:** Just remember this while using the `=` and `==` operators

- `=`   is for **assignment**
- `==`  is for **comparison**

Answer (score 0):

When you compare things in C++ you need to do it like:

```
if (a == b)
```

and not

```
if (a = b)
```

The latter will assign b to a and return the value of a.